# What is IVisual's enumerateObjectInstances method used for?

Tags: powerbi

Here is the specification of enumerateObjectInstances from IVisual interface:

```
/** Gets the set of objects that the visual is currently displaying. */
enumerateObjectInstances?(options: EnumerateVisualObjectInstancesOptions): VisualObjectInstanceEnumeration;
```

Every sample and built-in IVisual I looked at implements its own enumerateObjectInstances.  From looking at each, what it does is build up and return an array of information about some or all visual objects that the visual is displaying, usually filtered depending on parameters given to the method.  But the method doesn't seem to be invoked in basic operation.  What is its purpose, is it just for testing?

Answer (score 4):

Alright, answering my own question.  AsterPlot custom visual is helpful in explaining what enumerateObjectInstances does, because it has a comment:

```
// This function retruns the values to be displayed in the property pane for each object.
// Usually it is a bind pass of what the property pane gave you, but sometimes you may want to do
// validation and return other values/defaults
public enumerateObjectInstances... {
  var instances: VisualObjectInstance[] = [];
  switch (options.objectName) {
    case 'label':
      ...
      instances.push(label);
      break;
    case 'outerLine':
      ...
      instances.push(outerLine);
      break;
  }
  return instances;
}
```

Importantly, those switch cases, "label" and "outerLine", match the names of properties in AsterPlot's capabilities object:

```
public static capabilities: VisualCapabilities = {
  ...
  objects: {
    ...
    label: {
      ...
    },
    outerLine: {
      ...
    }
  }
};
```

So enumerateObjectInstances is used by the Power BI app to populate and hook up the format pane of the visual.  In AsterPlot's example, if you remove enumerateObjectInstances, you will not be able to toggle whether the outer line shows or not.